# Easier way to write this secondary function?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've got a program that will launch nmap scans on a given host, adding the arguments I have:

```
def _get_all_info(self):
    """
    get all the information from the scan
    """

    def __add_options():
        option_list = []
        if self.opts is not None:
            for opt in self.opts:
                if opt not in lib.attacks.nmap_scan.nmap_opts:
                    logger.warning(set_color(
                        "option '{}' is not a valid nmap option "
                        "skipping...".format(opt)
                    ))
                else:
                    option_list.append(opt)
        return " ".join(options_list)

    scanned_data = self.NM.scan(self.ip, ports=self.ports, arguments=__add_options())
    if self.pretty:
        scanned_data = json.dumps(scanned_data, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
    return scanned_data
```

Is there an easier way I can write the __add_options part?

Comment: You could remove the `def` line and use `option_list` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [list comprehensions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) and drop the useless logging:

```
def __add_options():
    return " ".join([opt for opt in self.opts if opt in lib.attacks.nmap_scan.nmap_opts])
```